# How to concatenate some columns with different data of two rows which are having same email address, using python?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have to concatenate two or more rows of a csv file, which have same email id, but some columns will have varied values for the same email id in different rows.
Adding sample i/p and sample required o/p file and what I have tried and what result I am getting.

### sample i/p file:

[image]

```
email,real_email,policy,fr_details,fr_subduction,date
a@gmail.com,111_a@gmail.com,12345678,Covid_19 Questionnaire,Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire,10.1.2022
a@gmail.com,111_a@gmail.com,12345678,ID Proof,Photograph is not available,10.1.2022
b@gmail.com,111_b@gmail.com,12345678,Covid_19 Questionnaire,Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire,10.1.2022
b@gmail.com,111_b@gmail.com,12345678,Pan Card / Form 60,Pan Card / Form 60 is not Submitted,10.1.2022
```

### sample required o/p:

[image]

```
"email","real_email","policy","fr_details","fr_subduction","fr_details1","fr_subduction1","date"
"a@gmail.com","111_a@gmail.com","12345678","Covid_19 Questionnaire","Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire","ID Proof","Photograph is not available","10.1.2022"
"b@gmail.com","111_b@gmail.com","12345678","Covid_19 Questionnaire","Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire","Pan Card / Form 60","Pan Card / Form 60 is not Submitted","10.1.2022"
```

(so for example; If a@gmail.com is repeated 3 times with 3 different `fr_*` values then output will have one more additional column: `fr_details2`, `fr_subdesction2`.)

### code I have written:

```
import csv

def get_elem(x):
    x=x.tolist()
    if x[0]==x[1]:
        return x[0]
    else:
        y=x[0]+","+x[1]
        return y


df = pandas.read_csv('in.csv')
df1=df.groupby('email',as_index=False).agg(get_elem)
df1.reset_index(drop= True)
df1.to_csv('out.csv', sep=',', index=False, header=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

### output for the above code:

[image]

```
"email","real_email","policy","fr_details","fr_subduction","date"
"a@gmail.com","111_a@gmail.com","12345678","Covid_19 Questionnaire,ID Proof","Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire,Photograph is not available","10.1.2022"
"b@gmail.com","111_b@gmail.com","12345678","Covid_19 Questionnaire,Pan Card / Form 60","Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire,Pan Card / Form 60 is not Submitted","10.1.2022"
```

with my code the output the `fr_*` columns are getting concatenated in the same column, but I need to separate these columns such that they are getting repeated as many times as they occurs in a sequence: `fr_details(n)`, `fr_subdesction(n)`, for the same email id

Comment: How about setting the e-mail address as index ´set_index()´? This lets you easily combine two dataframes simply by concatenating them. But you need to be sure that the addresses are unique

Comment: Can you give your everything as text rather than photos...

Comment: @BeRT2me hi! I just have added the text as you suggested,  actually the text files were not coming in a beautified way, so I though of adding ss.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the `fr_` like columns, then drop the `fr` columns to get the remaining columns which can be used for grouping, now create a sequential counter using cumcount to identify unique rows per group, then pivot the dataframe to reshape, finally flatten the multiindex columns if required:

```
fr = df.filter(like='fr_')
keys = df.columns.drop(fr).tolist()

df['col'] = df.groupby(keys).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
out = df.pivot(keys, 'col')
out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Result

```
>>> out
                                                          fr_details_1        fr_details_2                        fr_subduction_1                      fr_subduction_2
email       real_email      policy   date                                                                                                                             
a@gmail.com 111_a@gmail.com 12345678 10.1.2022  Covid_19 Questionnaire            ID Proof  Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire          Photograph is not available
b@gmail.com 111_b@gmail.com 12345678 10.1.2022  Covid_19 Questionnaire  Pan Card / Form 60  Please provide Covid_19 questionnaire  Pan Card / Form 68 is not Submitted
```

Comment: actually the fr_* columns are supposed to be after policy column and before date column,
and fr_details_1 should followed by fr_subduction_1.
I have been trying to use the logic you provided to get the required result by tweaking here and there, seems not to work